# Dots on images, visible in viewfinder, with lens off

Tags: dust

Nikon d750
 dot on image - always same place. Visible speck through viewfinder in the right place , with lens off.
I know it can't be any sensor mark seen via viewfinder, none the less I've cleaned the sensor. 
I think I'm right in thinking dot on mirror can't effect the image. I've carefully wiped mirror. 
Where is the speck? 
Thanks. My first dslr. Missing film already, Tom

Comment: It sounds like dirt in the viewfinder assembly.  Can you confirm this problem speck is not visible in photos ?  This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9uNX36szLQ) may help.  Same problem can happen with film SLRs by the way.

Comment: Thanks, Steven. Speck visible on images and through viewfinder without lens on.

Comment: I confess that's perplexing to me.  To get a visible speck in an image would require dirt very close to the sensor itself and I don't see a way to get both a viewfinder speck and a corresponding image spot from just one cause.  A greater mind than mine is needed for this problem. :-)

Comment: Perhaps two specks that optically look to be in same place in ration to image but are in separate parts of camera. I could always clean the sensor again. Am I right in thinking the mirror plays no part in this? Not effecting the image but I be seeing something on the mirror in the viewfinder?  I will check the video you posted, thanks. T

Comment: In both DSLRs and SLRs the mirror sits down to redirect the light to the viewfinder until you shoot at which point it flips up so all light goes to the sensor/film.  So you are correct that the mirror cannot affect the image formed by the sensor.  There is normally a second smaller mirror used to direct light to the AF system to get focus, but I don't think that would be the path of both sensor and viewfinder at the same time.  Here a link to a post on [DPReview](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/59489351) with a diagram and brief explanation of that secondary mirror.

Comment: Could you post a crop of an image with the spot showing *using a lens* ?  Something at a narrow aperture like f16 or f22 and similarly something at a wide aperture like f4.  Maybe this would show something useful.  It might help someone figure something out.

Comment: Hi Stephen. apologies for the delay in replying. re dot photos with small large aperture. took several with both ends of f stop. no signs on image at all. dot is still visible through view finder. I found  a ring stain on today's photos in a different place. cleaned the sensor and that has gone. It could be that whatever  the visible dot is  as seen through the viewfinder is in close enough visual proximity to the dot I had on the images but not related. I've zoomed in on the last few photos and nothing. So whatever that dot is, it is not affecting the image.

Comment: StephenG  thanks for your time. got cut off.